# YouTube video choppy on Chrome, fine on Firefox

Tags: video, radeon, youtube

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, ATI HD4850 graphics card, radeon driver.

Chrome has been my browser for years, but for the past few months, YouTube videos and page scrolling have become choppy. By choppy, I mean there are horizontal lines appearing either in the video that I am watching or on the page that I am scrolling. For the page scrolling, it appears when I am scrolling fast (using the mouse wheel), and for videos, it seems to be appearing when the video is in a "fast movement" segment.

I have resolved the choppy scrolling by enabling the fast scrolling option, now that I've found where it moved to. How do I fix choppy videos? I have switched to Firefox for watching videos, as they are playing fine there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing you can try that solved the issue for me is enabling hardware acceleration.

Here is you how you can do that:

1. Navigate to `chrome://flags` in the Chrome URL bar
2. Click **Enable** on the **Override software rendering list** as shown here:
   [image: Override software rendering list]
3. Restart Chrome
4. Optionally restart your computer

And it should be fixed

Comment: That fixed it! You're awesome!

Comment: Glad it worked!